# Socket.io disconnection event triggers after long

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ionic-framework

I am just trying to create a simple app using Socket.io. I am trying to send a notification (technically, emit an event) to all the connected users, if a particular user, User X, has disconnected, that User X has left or has disconnected.
Here is my server side code.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('Connected! ' + socket.id);

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  for(var i=0;i<onlineUsers.length;i++)
  {
    if(onlineUsers[i].socketId == socket.id)
    {
        var newMessage = {};
        newMessage.socketId = onlineUsers[i].socketId;
        newMessage.fullName = onlineUsers[i].fullName;
        newMessage.message = newMessage.fullName + " IS DISCONNETED!";
        io.emit('newMessage', newMessage);

        onlineUsers.splice(i,1);
        console.log('splicing id ' + socket.id);
    }
  }
}
```

I guess that the code is executing but takes long to emit the disconnection event. I receive the disconnection message about 2 minutes after the client had disconnected. Why does it take so long? What might be the wrong in this code?

I also cannot understand when exactly the client is considered as disconnected. If the app closes, or the browser closes or the internet goes down?

Thanks in advance.

**Update: I have a test deployment on Cloud9 and my live deployment is on Azure Cloud. I have realized that Cloud9 works just perfect, this seems like an issue with Azure.**

**Update 2: Whenever I disconnect/close/refresh my web client, I immediately get the disconnected event emitted by the server. The same does not happen for my mobile client. Why?**

Comment: Socket io should sent heartbeat (aka ping) signals every I think 15s by default. If the client fails to respond then it is considered disconnected. Also when he sends TCP closing packet (i.e. when he disconnects gracefully). However 2min lag seems to be too long. But maybe it's the network lag? How is `onlineUsers` array filled? I think we need more details, the code seems to be ok.

Comment: Well rest of the code is working just perfect. I added this newMessage and all 5 lines today. The online users array is filled on connection event.